# Making your own shortcuts on Windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Windows Vista, and I was wondering if I can put shortcuts for applications.Like for example, if I press a certain combination of keys I get notepad, or something like that. If those shortcuts were already there, how can I know them?

Another thing, if I have an application that runs on media files for example, can I add it on the " Right Click" menu when I right click on media files. I hope you got that :)

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For keyboard shortcuts, the program has to be on the start menu. [MS has a KB on how to do it.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142898) Alternatively, you can download software to manage this, but it's commonly unnecessary.

Editing the context menu for file types is a bit more involved, I wouldn't recommend it for a beginner, but there are [directions available from the Vista Club](http://www.winvistaclub.com/e11.html).

Comment: Thanx, that was really helpful :)